# Laravel WhereIn Doesn't Accept Array Value

Tags: laravel

I have this on my blade file:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'my_route_name']) }}

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
  <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download
  </button>

  {{ Form::hidden('my_ids', $my_ids) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Checking on the chrome's developer mode, the value of my hidden textbox named `my_ids` is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Upon clicking the **Download** button, it goes on my controller:

```
$results= Model::whereIn('id', $request->my_ids)->get();
```

This is where I am getting an error.

DD-ing `dd($request->my_ids)` on my controller gives me `"[1,2,3,4,5,6]"`.

However, if I just put the values directly on the eloquent query like below, **it would work**.

```
$results= Model::whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4,5,6])->get();
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: it says `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` then it's highlighting my `$results= Model::whereIn('id', $request->my_ids)->get();` query

Comment: I assume that `$request->my_ids` gives you an array like string however you can improve your query with `Model::findMany($request->my_ids);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dd shows that $request->my_ids is a string, therefore you must parse it before you use it as array.

Try

```
$results= Model::whereIn('id', json_decode($request->my_ids))->get();
```

Comment: @kapitan my pleasure! :)